# Why can't I use MVC Experience Editor

Tags: experience-editor, mvc

I am getting some strange characters in my View when using Experience Editor.

This is the main layout;

```
@model RenderingModel

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira+Sans:100,100i,300,300i,400,400i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Patua+One" rel="stylesheet">


    <title>Trees for Wildlife</title>

    <link href="Css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="Css/custom_css.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="Css/NWF.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <!-- Owl Carousel Stylesheets -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Css/owl.carousel.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Css/owl.theme.default.css">


    <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.0/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/custom.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/owl.carousel.js"></script>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>

    <div id="main-mobile-search" class="collapse">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Search</button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div id="banner-nav-container" class="microsite-banner">

        <div class="home-banner-overlay"> </div>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>

        @Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("head-content")
        @Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("header-content")
        @Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("HeroImage")

    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("main-content")
    </div>


    @Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("microsite-footer-sub-navigation")
    @Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("footer-content")
    @Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("footerNavigation")

    <a href="#top">
        <div style="position: relative">
            <div id="back-to-top" class="hidden-xs">
                <img class="center-block" src="images/arrow-up-circle.svg" onerror="this.onerror=null; this.src='arrow-up-circle.png'" alt="Back to Top">
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>

    <script>
        $('a[href*="top"]:not([href="top"])').click(function () {
            if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
                var target = $(this.hash);
                target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
                if (target.length) {
                    $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: target.offset().top
                    }, 1000);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    </script>

    <div id="mobile_social_sticky" class="hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
        <div id="mobile-donate-sticky">
            Donate <img class="heart-icon" src="images/heart-icon.svg" onerror="this.onerror=null; this.src='images/heart-icon.png'" alt="Donate">
        </div>

        <div id="mobile-facebook-sticky" class="mobile-sticky-item">
            <img class="center-block" src="images/facebook-footer.svg" onerror="this.onerror=null; this.src='images/facebook-footer.png'" alt="Visit our Facebook">
        </div>

        <div id="mobile-twitter-sticky" class="mobile-sticky-item">
            <img class="center-block" src="images/twitter-footer.svg" onerror="this.onerror=null; this.src='images/twitter-footer.png'" alt="Visit our Twitter">
        </div>

        <div id="mobile-email-sticky" class="mobile-sticky-item">
            <img class="center-block" src="images/email-footer.svg" onerror="this.onerror=null; this.src='images/email-footer.png'" alt="Email to a Friend">
        </div>


    </div>


    <script>
        var searchIcon = document.getElementById("search-icon");
        var closeIcon = document.getElementById("close-icon");
        TweenMax.set(closeIcon, { x: -100 });

        searchIcon.addEventListener('click', function () {
            TweenMax.to(searchIcon, .5, { x: -100 });
            TweenMax.to(closeIcon, .5, { x: 0 });
            console.log('search clicked');
        });

        closeIcon.addEventListener('click', function () {
            TweenMax.to(searchIcon, .5, { x: 0 });
            TweenMax.to(closeIcon, .5, { x: -100 });
            console.log('close clicked');
        });
    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

This is a partial MVC Controller Rendering in the placeholder `head-content`, which works great in Preview mode but when I try to work with it in Experience Editor, I have two problems:

1. I have all of these weird markup

   `here","icon":"/temp/iconcache/office/16x16/add.png","disabledIcon":"/temp/add_disabled16x16.png","isDivider":false,"tooltip":"Add a new rendering to the '{0}' placeholder.","type":""},{"click":"chrome:placeholder:editSettings","header":"","icon":"/temp/iconcache/office/16x16/window_gear.png","disabledIcon":"/temp/window_gear_disabled16x16.png","isDivider":false,"tooltip":"Edit the placeholder settings.","type":""}],"contextItemUri":"sitecore://master/{7CAFC3BA-B846-46DF-8B0D-2AE218541158}?lang=en&ver=1","custom":{"allowedRenderings":[],"editable":"false"},"displayName":"header-content","expandedDisplayName":null}{"commands":[{"click":"chrome:rendering:sort","header":"Change position","icon":"/temp/iconcache/office/16x16/document_size.png","disabledIcon":"/temp/document_size_disabled16x16.png","isDivider":false,"tooltip":"Move component.","type":""},{"click":"javascript:Sitecore.PageModes.PageEditor.postRequest('webedit:componentoptions(renderingId={3A64C4E1-B1D8-47EF-AB5C-D013F60E81A0},id={7CAFC3BA-B846-46DF-8B0D-2AE218541158},referenceId={49929205-3267-42`
2. I added a placeholder in my layout in Sitecore, and then in the Presentation details I set a rendering to the `main-content` placeholder.  I gave it a Datasource and assigned some allowed renderings

Normally, in Experience Editor mode I would have a tab, called "Add Here" when I press the "add new component" in the experience editor, nothing happens.

Note, I did get a message the `webedit.css` is not found, I don't know what this is or where to get it, but I checked my include `/AppConfig/Include` for `Sitecore.MvcExperienceEditor.config` and it is there. I just don't know what to do.

I have worked with Sitecore MVC successfully in the past but I did not set this up.

Comment: Can you post the code for the View that is returned by the Controller Rendering?

Answer (score 1):

So it sounds like you might be having a couple of issues.  For the issue with weird mark up refer to this article: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/286042

To sum that issue up, if you have jquery on the page, the Prototype Javascript library might conflict with your Jquery library.  To get past this issue, just use Jquery in the No-Conflict Mode.

Also you may want to wrap the `@Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("head-content")` placeholder in a Div, like this:

```
<div>
    @Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("head-content")
</div>
```

For the second issue, this probably means you don't have an Placeholder settings defined.  It will not show an option to `Add Here` until you configure placeholder settings.  Or as a second option, you would need to enable setting `WebEdit.PlaceholdersEditableWithoutSettings` and set the value to true.  This will allow you to use the experience editor and add renderings to placeholders without having placeholder settings defined.

Comment: hey thanks, I have been following your videos, I have been working on and off with Sitecore since 6.3 ... I did site last year in 8.0 and I didn't have any issues, but now I am working with a small team and we are all in architecture mode. this thing with jquery no-conflict ... where on the page does that go, at the top or bottom. I don't think we have a $document.Ready( function(){}); on this page, the markup was done by someone else. whatever missing webedit.css could that be causing some issue? can I email you directly?

Comment: Hi Thank you!  The Experience Editor can be tricky sometimes.  I actually personally think it might be the wrapping of the div around your placeholders.  As for the Jquery no conflict, this link here might be helpful: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Comment: I will try all of your suggestions. thank you again

Comment: Let me know if that doesn't work and I'll brain storm on something else :-)

Comment: no that did not work, but I did figure that my "add this " tab is working, it is just hidden, and I probably need some padding about the div

Comment: well, I added this to the the <head> tag before the <body> tag

Comment: <script>
        var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    </script>

Comment: then changed the jquery from $() to $J() ... still isn't working

Comment: could it also have something to do with webedit.css missing, I can't seem to find this anywhere in the solution. but I didn't build the solution

Comment: Just for a test, can you disable your css/js and see if we have a conflict with your css/js or an actual Sitecore configuration issue.

Comment: Hmm I spun up a sandbox environment with the layout code you provided.  Now most of the scripts/css don't work because I don't have them locally, but once I enabled WebEdit.PlaceholdersEditableWithoutSettings setting to true, I was able to select and add renderings to the experience.  So it's quite likely that it might be something in the scripts that's interfering with the Experience Editor.  Since my resources aren't loading locally.  So try Chris's suggestion and see if it works correctly then.

Comment: Hi Dylan, thank you for all of your time on this. the problem was simply that I did not have "webedit.css" in the root of the website. i talked to my colleague and he had the .webedit.css in his so he sent me a copy and I placed it in the root, now experience editor works ... now I just I am able to add placeholders and I can move forward. I am going to view your video on glassmapper because we are not currently using this and I think we should. I have used it before. but, since we are non for profit, we are sort of constrained on budget. we shall see. but thank you for all of your help!!

Comment: Yeah I would definitely recommend the use of an ORM/Wrapper, such as Glass or Synthesis